# How to create installsheild msp using Msbuild task?

Tags: msbuild, installshield, msbuild-task

I am creating installshield msp by manual steps.

I knew there is a msbuild task which could be used to create msi.

But, Is there any way to create it using Msbuild task.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of InstallShield you are using, so this may or may not be available to you. If you're using a recent enough version, you can specify the `PatchConfiguration` attribute for the `InstallShield` task, as described in the help topic [Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild)](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield18helplib/MSBuild.htm).